# Rewrite piece-wise function as an integral with given condition

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, partial-derivative, piecewise-continuity

I have the following piece wise function. Suppose that $f : \!R \rightarrow \!R$ has derivatives of all orders.

Also, $f(0)=0$
$$
g(t)=
\begin{cases}
 f(t)/t \quad t\neq 0 \\
 f'(0)\quad t=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

***Prove that $g(t) = \frac{f(t)}{t} = \int_{0}^{1} f'(tx)dx$***

Below is what I have tried:

Using FTC, $\int_{0}^{1} f'(tx)dx = f(t \cdot 1) - f(t \cdot 0) = f(t) - f(0)$

Since it is provided that $f(0) = 0$, now I have just $f(t)$

And the proof becomes $g(t) = \frac{f(t)}{t} = f(t)$, for this to be true, $t$ need to be $1$. But I cannot find a reason to justify that.

Am I on the right track? Or did I mess up from the beginning?

Comment: +1 for including all the relevant context. New users need to take a lesson from you.

Comment: Since you have already figured out the problem I don't see much scope for new answers. You may accept your own answer so that the question is removed from list of "unanswered questions".

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer until 2 days later

Comment: Oh forgot that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I need to substitute $u=tx$ as a function of $x$

Now I have $\frac{du}{t}=dx$, put it back into the integral $\int_{0}^{1}f'(tx)dx$. This gives $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f'(u)}{t}du$$

Evaluate this integral gives $\frac{f(t)}{t} - \frac{f(0)}{t}$

And since $f(0) = 0$, then $g(t) = \frac{f(t)}{t}$